# When Raspberry Pi is shutdown, server send SMS to it to boot it back up

Tags: internet

I have multiple raspberry pi compute modules that will be placed in remote locations. If any of them shutdown unexpectedly, I can't travel and reboot them. They are connected via 3G modem to the internet. Is it possible that server sends them a message to boot up the system? How would this be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a second device that can control the power state of the Pi and have that also talk over your 3G modem to the server.

You can't restart a system in software without a second system; if the whole system crashes. If you just mean your software you can simply use one of the many tools out there to auto restart software that crashed (f.e. [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever)).

If you need to have a hardware reset the only option without a second system would be to use the internal [Watchdog](http://blog.ricardoarturocabral.com/2013/01/auto-reboot-hung-raspberry-pi-using-on.html) of the BCM chipset.
That wont make it possible to reset the pi over 3G but you can have the pi reset if your application or the whole system crashes.